# JQuery calendar/events plugin for generic weekly view

Tags: jquery, calendar, appointment

There are a lot of calendar plugins for JQuery out there! I'm looking for a plugin that is not quite a calendar plugin. I'm looking to show weekly events that I pull from a database and render them similar to this:

http://www.gymboreeclasses.com/calendar.do?fCode=361&sCode=939&mode=calendar

In particular:
- no date, just day (the type of information I have is name of event, day of week, start time, end time, category)
- different colors for different categories of event
- ability to render overlapped events next to each other
- ability to provide more information about an event on click (eg: a description)

I'm not looking for the ability to change or add events in the plugin. I just want to display events already in a database.

Anyone know of anything that could fit the bill?

Answer (score 1):

This is the best plugin available on the web.
Check it out Might be helpful for you.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference

Comment: are you got any other script? or Do I give an example how to use refereed script for specific use as you want?